# System crash on loki 4.1

Tags: release-loki, nvidia

I have a problem after updating my drivers for the nvidia with the software update programm and at the same time I ticked a box under it saying to use my processor.It asked for a restart to take place and  after that the system starts by booting some commands instead of that e letter which was appearing and never opens up really . As soon as I try to press a button on the keyboard or move the mouse goes to suspend mode. Please somebody!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue quite easily finally. Opened the terminal with alt+ctrl+f1 and followed the first command to remove all nvidia from the following topic: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely
Thanks everyone for sharing his knowledge -experience!

Comment: Please try to add a descriptive / detailed answer so that someone in future facing the same problem can solve their problem easily. And best practice of adding resource is to add the resource here and then link the resource.